# How can I share my CV hosted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I generally want to share my CV by URL such as:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/employer/340563
```

However, I found that it is not public; access such url without user identity would redirect to login page.

And all the featured job is not universally applicable using the very CV that I composed at Stack Overflow. Or someone just offered me a job that saving me from such poverty state.

Comment: Make your cv public in the settings.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/zJLpZV0e

Comment: thanks for your screen snap, i mean, let me checkout ...

Comment: stackoverflow-job is the best CV hosting/composing system that i ever encountered  , i believe i also have the ability to create such CS hosting system, but  stackoverflow fit all my idea for improvements(such search engine indexability ) , does that mean my skill is redundant? real hard to find a creative/challenging job. only useful as loser to take blame for other's mistake/stupidity

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you are asking should you build a CV hosting / composing system like SO, that's all up to you.  Competition is always good, just remember that they have invested people time and a lot of reusability from the se sites to create such a tool.  It isn't easy.  That didn't stop people like Steve Jobs from building upon his apple products to get them where they are today.

Comment: no offence indeed , i am not a apple user. should programmer use apple stuff ? i know good programmer do able to afford them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your cv public through the edit cv settings.

Here's a screen shot of it:

[image]

Steps:

1. Go to the jobs tab
2. Click the tab edit cv
3. There is a blue **settings** button on the right side, click on it
4. Your cv public / private settings on the left.
5. Make your cv public and you can then generate a url for your cv, such as mine: https://stackoverflow.com/cv/jhermiz

Comment: what does it mean when CV is private?

Comment: It means employers and recruiters and virtually no one except you can see it.

Comment: So there is no way to make it public to employers but private to general public?

Comment: Girogi question is how?

Comment: just was curious if that was possible. Anyway thanks for response

Comment: When did StackOverflow drop the CV feature?  I missed the memo...

Comment: @EricBolinger jobs was sunset a few weeks ago.

Comment: Many thanks @JonH.  I appreciate it.